# Organizing a Visual Studio Solution with common source for multiple projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, organization

The title describes what I try to achieve since I started developing in VS2013.
[image]

I basically have a folder which contains all the projects linked to the solution (in this case, EditorRenderer, Engine, FileEditor and PhysicsWorkbench are project directories) which share the same source files which are placed in Source folder.

[image]

I organized the Source folder as an Filter in Visual Studio and I made filters to match the entire folder hierarchy that Source has in Windows Explorer. The problem is when I have 2 projects and I add a new folder to the Source, I have to add the folder and the files individually for each project. My question is: Is there any way to make a global project that will be included in every other project that I choose, and to make changes only one time?

Comment: Add a static library project to your solution, move common source files there. Then just link all the other projects (which would no longer refer to the shared files) with that library.

Comment: It may be me who doesn't know to do this correctly but I can't manage to get it working because of the SDL2/glew/assimp/SOIL libraries that are needed to compile the source code.